# What's the right approach for updating unit tests, when logic has changed?

Tags: unit-testing

To make it simple: first, myFunction returned array with two keys ('foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2), and I was testing for existence of each of them.

Later business logic changed, and myFunction should return only one key, array('foo' => 1).

Should I:
a) Remove tests for second key ('bar') from unit tests?
b) or test directly if this key is not existing in return array of myFunction?

First answer seems more logical - as I'm not testing any other keys like ('blabla', 'xman') and so on. But on the other hand I'd like to be sure that I have my logic updated everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You should test against your current requirement. In your case it includes that the refactoring has been done properly :D

In any case:

If your array should return only `foo` you test whether it returns only `foo` or not. If it returns more than `foo` or something different, the test should fail. If you have a list of keys, you test all these keys whether they are valid or not. There cannot be keys that were not defined in your test set up.

Comment: So it seems that the best solution is to test if result and expected arrays are equal (all kesy are equal, and there are non additional ones). Thx.

Answer (score 0):

By definition unit test means testing one functionality in atomic way. You may use Red, Green, refactor approach to fix that problem. This describes TDD approach http://techno-fear-killer.blogspot.com/